# Wit/location gives wrong results

Tags: wit.ai

I have a Wit/Messenger bot that needs te be given a location in user input in order to run a few API calls, today i was trying some dummy input like "sfsgsgj dkldh" and the whole sentence is interpreted as a location by Wit.

Do you have an idea about what might be wrong?

Comment: I'm having the same issue right now, except with names. When someone adds their full name "John Smith" it's a coin toss as to whether or not it's tagged as a wit/contact or wit/location.